# Change abstract title in IEEEtran when used with other language

Tags: luatex, ieeetran, abstract

When I use the [ieeetran](/questions/tagged/ieeetran)-class with a german [babel](/questions/tagged/babel)-package loaded, the title of the abstract automatically gets translated to ***Zusammenfassung***. However I'd like it to be ***Kurzfassung***.

The solution one can find all over the web, is just to use:

```
\def\abstractname{Kurzfassung}
```

Why is that approach not working in my case?

I use lualatex, here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\def\abstractname{Kurzfassung}
\def\IEEEkeywordsname{Stichwörter}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords} 
    myKeyword
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Einleitung}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

---

But the appearance of the abstract remains unchanged in the german default ***Zusammenfassung***:

[image]

Comment: `\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand\abstractname{Kurzfassung}}` http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=latexwords

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is there a duplicate question somewhere? Otherwise it would be a helpful answer I'd assume. Thank you!

Comment: I'm rather certain that there is a duplicate somewhere.